# BigCommerce api - How to designate which option value is the default?

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I would like to designate which option value should be used as the default value.  Is there any way to do this in the BigCommerce Api?

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge, it is not possible to set a default option value via the API.